# Setting auto increment lower than the current highest value?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a MySQL table with an auto-increment ID field. I'm filling the table with data from one source, with its own unique ID (starting from around 4 million up). I also want to insert my own data but don't want it to conflict with the IDs already in the database.

Ideally I'd just insert it all at a lower ID. However, I have to use a function outside of my control (a built-in Joomla function) which will insert a new row if the ID is 0, but try and update it if it's any other number.

So obviously if I try and insert a new row with and ID of 1, it will try to update the row with ID of 1, which doesn't exist. So no data gets inserted.

I've tried setting the auto-increment value lower than the current max id but it doesn't work. Is there another solution to my problem?

**UPDATE**: To try and clarify my question, I have data from another source with a high ID (from 4 million and increasing). I want to insert rows with a low ID, from 1 and up (the external source will not conflict with this). However, for the reasons described above, I can't just find an unused low ID and use that, I have to either use zero or find some other solution.

Comment: That doesn't explain *why*:  Is there a good reason to preserve the ID from the other source?  Is there some reason to merge the data yet keep it segregated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: store the external IDs in a different field!

The IDs that are coming from the external source are now stored in an "extid" field, so I can keep a check on that field (for my own updating). I made the main ID field an auto-incrementing primary key, which I can use to refer to the articles in various places.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to preserve the IDs from the other database?  If so, how about a bulk insert with `mysqldump`?

Otherwise, why not simply let the auto increment do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the last id inserted? If so, you can put this into your logic:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_id
```

And use that to get the last ID inserted and put that in your new record.

Answer (score 0):

If the function you're referring to is `JTable::store()`, you could create a class extending `JTable`, then write the `store()` function to behave the way you want.

Comment: This might be the easiest solution. I could copy the function and modify it to suit my needs.

Comment: Sure. Also take a look at the LDAP authentication plugin for a practical example.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to do it programmatically and bypass the fact that the table has a auto-increment identity.   I would programmatically start counting from row #1 until you find a blank row and then manually specify that as the row-id  instead of relying on the auto-increment.

Comment: But as I said (or tried to anyway), if I call the store function with an ID other than 0, it tries to update the table and not insert the row.

Comment: ahh... is "store" a function in code or is it a stored procedure?  it still sounds like it can be solved programatically.   the sql server itself isn't "forcing" you to do it that way I dont think... instead, its the store function that is doing that.  i guess if you dont have access to that function, your screwed, but you can probably still bypass it by making your own connection to the SQL server.